# I accidentally deactivated the internet of my VPS (How to enable it again if I lost the connection?)

Tags: vps, internet

I accessed the: Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network and Sharing Center. So, I clicked in "Ethernet". Oponed the "Ethernet Status" for me and I clicked in "Disable".

So, I lost my connection!!!

My intention was change my IP, but now, I can't login anymore, I need help!

[image: network settings screenshot]

PS1: My VPS is a Free VPS of Amazon.

PS2: I'm asking help here because the Amazon's Forum didn't allow me open a thread there. I received the following msg: "Your account is not ready for posting messages yet. Please try again later."

PS3: I ask help for Amazon's technical support, but, probably they will not answer me, because the Amazon don't give tech support for free VPS.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, go to console and try rebooting the instance.

If there is a Remote Desktop Service (RDS) running you should be able to connect and fix the issue.

See [Amazon's documentation for more info](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/screenshot-service.html).